# How to pull Email and password only from a text file in CMD?

Tags: batch, cmd.exe

**I have a text file named **file.txt** ,**

**Image of .File.txt**
[combo pic of .txt file](https://i.stack.imgur.com/hCy0F.png)

****I am running the below code, to filter only mail:pass from the above text file file.txt****

```
@rem.^
                Combo: testing123mail@gmail.com:password^
                As Combo:^
                abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz@gmail.com:ajfbdf^ **Unwanted Text with symbols, numbers or text , basically anything....**^
                
                As Combo: hadvsfhia@ahfjbadj.com:password@1^ **Unwanted Text with symbols, numbers or text , basically anything....** ^
                iloveu@gmail.com:passypassyword123^
                goldenmammy@hotmail.com:youtube123^

@echo off & type nul >.\mail.txt & for /f "tokens=*delims=" %%i in ('type combo.txt')do (
echo=%%~i|find "@">nul && for /f "tokens=01,02,03delims=:" %%I in ('call echo=%%~i')do (
echo=%%~I|find "@">nul && set "_m_p=%%I:%%J" || set "_m_p=%%~J:%%~K") && for /f %%E in ('
echo=%%~J')do cmd /v/c "echo=!_m_p: =!"|find "@")>>.\mail.txt ||>nul call nul 2>nul 2>&1
```

**Obtained output in mail.txt**
[Image of output](https://i.stack.imgur.com/bvnRf.png)

**Expected Output in mail.txt,**

```
abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz@gmail.com:ajfbdf
hadv@ahfjbadj.com:password@1
test123mail@gmail.com:password
iloveu@gmail.com:passypassyword123
goldenmammy@hotmail.com:youtube123
```

**The mail id and passwords will be different in each textline of the text file. Above given mail id and passwords are  random for example.**

**Kindly requesting anyone to share the code that helps to get expected output .I am pretty unfamiliar with batch as i just started learning, so i truly need help. Thankyou in advance.**

Comment: Please [edit] your question and include the output you are currently getting from your code.

Comment: @DavidPostill
Yeah , I have added now.

Comment: Please read [Debugging batch files](http://www.robvanderwoude.com/battech_debugging.php)

Comment: @DavidPostill That would have been great , but i am new to this and tried many times, but still no positive results, thats why I asked in theCommunity. Thank you for your Response Sir!!!

Comment: answered.......

Comment: @DavidPostill Thank you sir for the response. Regarding pipes i indicated in quotes as *Unwanted Text with symbols, numbers or text , basically anything....** .Regarding  the batch file of yours  its running ok , however it pulled all other things except mail:pass in mail.txt. Seems you removed your answer, its ok and working if you edit that one sir !!

Comment: Please [edit] the question and provide a single real example text file. At the moment the example in the question does not match the image.

Comment: @DavidPostill Its done sir. Could it be possible for you to post the answer of yours too  after some  modification on same batch file? I know i got the answer but i want variations in answers to learn more. Thank you so much for your time.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Get each line (%%a) and split it into "words" (`%%b`).
Test each "word" if it matches the desired format (containing `@` and `:`).
If it matches, `echo` it.
Finally, redirect the output to the results file.

```
@echo off
setlocal
(for /f "tokens=*" %%a in (combo.txt) do (
  for %%b in (%%a) do (
    echo "%%b"|findstr "@.*:" >nul && echo %%b
  )
))>mail.txt
type mail.txt
```

Comment: This one seems to be the best solution it gets the email and password even if it is not at the beginning of the text file....

Comment: Yeah It checked the whole page and pulled the email and pass , no matter its position in the .txt file.

Answer (score 0):

Try this code, you have to drag and drop the text file to the batch file. It should add "mail" to the filename of the original file.

```
@echo off

if not "%~x1"==".txt" exit

for /f "tokens=1-2 delims=: " %%a in ('type "%~1" ^|find /i "@"') do >>"%~n1.mail.txt" echo %%~a:%%b
```

[image]

Comment: TQ sir for your response. Seems your batch file worked with limitation of email:pass  needed to be in the front of the line .Well Works in that case! Thank you.

Comment: All the solutions are working as I thought /expected to work like.  Grateful to The Mentors and Sirs for their time for helping me out in this!